# Restrict radio button display, javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have a dropdown list. when clicking one of the items, it should display radio button to display.

I got till here. Now the question is

I have 4 radio buttons. I want to display 2 options and hide 2 options. in javascript.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you add a link to jsfiddle of your code.

Comment: <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      
 
         var f = document.getElementById("optiontext");
         var e = document.getElementById("agentr");  

         
         var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value.split('|');  
  
             
  if(value[0] == 1 || value[0] == 4 {
                        f.style.display = 'block';
                                      
                }else{

                         f.style.display = 'none';
                }

    });

</script>
<div id="optiontext">

Comment: Please help with your html code as well. Add your code to www.jsfiddle.net and share the link here. Thanks

Comment: Put it in jsfiddle.net (it is a website for js evaluation) so that everyone can run your code. It is easier to discuss and evaluate.

Comment: im not familiar with jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sunshine_sm2000/7gt5S/

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('#dropdownId').change(function() { //when the dropdown change
        var selectValue = $(this).val(); //Get it's value
        if (selectValue == 1) {
            $("#radioButtonId1").show();
            $("#radioButtonId2").show();
            $("#radioButtonId3").hide();
            $("#radioButtonId4").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

you can also use data on your Options to get options need to be displayed :

```
<input type = "radio" class="DependOnSelect" data-showonid="1,3,5" />
<input type = "radio" class="DependOnSelect" data-showonid="2,4,6" />
<input type = "radio" class="DependOnSelect" data-showonid="1,4,6" />
<input type = "radio" class="DependOnSelect" data-showonid="2,3,5" />

$(function() {
    $('#dropdownId').change(function() {
        var selectValue = $(this).val();
        if (selectValue == 1) {
            $('.DependOnSelect').each(function() { //for each Options
                var splited = $(this).data("showonid").split(','); 
                if (jQuery.inArray(selectValue, splited) > -1)
                    $(this).show(); // if the data-showonid contains the id, show it
                else
                    $(this).hide();                    
            });
        }
    });
}
```

[JSFIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J7Hy2/1/)
to disable element in jquery:

```
$('#ElementId').attr("disabled", "disabled);
```

to enable it :

```
$('#ElementId').removeAttr("disabled");
```

**in pure Javascript:**

Html:

```
<select id="dropdownId" onChange="jsFunction()">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="option" id="option1" />1
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="option" id="option2" />2
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="option" id="option3" />3
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="option" id="option4" />4
<br/>
```

javascript:

```
function jsFunction() {
    var myselect = document.getElementById("dropdownId");
    var value = myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value;

    if (value == 1) {
        document.getElementById('option1').disabled = 'disabled';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('option1').disabled = '';
    }

    if (value == 2) {
        document.getElementById('option2').disabled = 'disabled';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('option2').disabled = '';
    }

    if (value == 3) {
        document.getElementById('option3').disabled = 'disabled';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('option3').disabled = '';
    }

    if (value == 4) {
        document.getElementById('option4').disabled = 'disabled';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('option4').disabled = '';
    }
}
```

[JSFIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J7Hy2/3/)

Comment: can you tell me in javascript please. not jquery.

Comment: if you have object with the same id, i don't think it can be made...
do you have a jsfidle of your code?

Comment: ya but I need this javascript. My build does nt allow jquery

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as answered if it's what's you look for :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can disable any particular option by using "disabled"

```
<input type="radio" name="someName" value="someValue" id="someId" disabled>

Then get the two options you want to hide and make display = "none";
```

Comment: I need to do disable using javascript.

Comment: document.getElementById("someId").disabled=true;

Comment: all the options have same id

Comment: but each option has different value. I want to restrict radio button 3, radio button 4

Comment: "id" shouldn't be equal. For radio buttons the "name" will be equal.